# ARC: what's the difference between a member variable and property?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an NSArray object that is used throughout my UIViewController. I can either declare it as an ivar or as a property. Is there any advantage to either approach (considering I'm using ARC)?

**Option 1:**

```
@interface MyViewController {
    NSArray *_myArray;
}
@end
```

**Option 2:**

```
@interface MyViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *myArray;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties and ivars are conceptually quite different.

A *property* represents a logical component of your code.  It may, but need not, be backed by an ivar.  It could be <strike>dynamically generated</strike> calculated at run-time (like a view's `-frame`), etc.

An *ivar* is an actual allocated block of memory holding some data.

If you use properties (correctly), you get nice features like KVC/KVO compliance out of the box.  For this and other reasons it is often thought to be good practice, especially with the modern run-time, to declare all public interfaces in the form of properties, and internally back them with ivars (frequently using `@synthesize`) if appropriate.

Personally, I prefer to use properties for private data as well, both to make it easy to make public later if I want (just move the declaration to the header!) and to make it easy to provide custom implementations of properties (and setters/mutators) instead of relying on a simple ivar.

Since you mention ARC, I haven't used it much (yet) but I don't think it should make much of a difference as long as you declare your property correctly.

Comment: My question was specifically for private data. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: As far as ARC, properties and iVars loose their differences, for the most part. Previously, you had to be sure to set variables to the properties, as they had the risk of not being retained properly. Now, in ARC,

Comment: ive never heard of a property who doesnt have an ivar related to it, using @dynamic just means that the accessors will be provided somewhere later in the code so the compiler doesnt have to bug you about it not finding them. Unless you mean making these accessors perform other stuff unlerated to ivars in which case i think it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @LuisOscar "Dynamic" was a poor choice of words since that is also an Obj-C keyword, which wasn't what I intended; I will update my post.  The example I gave of `-frame` is a perfect example; there **is no** ivar for frame; it's calculated (what I meant by "dynamic") from the `-bounds` and (in `UIView`) `-center`. This is why, for example, `-frame` is meaningless when transforms are applied.

Comment: @ConradShultz even so, wouldnt the ivar of the frame be one of type CGRect? the fact that a transform makes this undefined doesnt have anything to do with it. That just means that since it might have rotations/scaling or something the views bounds should be used instead. (If you call for the frame you DO get a value, however this value could be wrong)

Comment: @LuisOscar No, `-frame` is calculated upon request.  It is not stored in an ivar (unless there is some caching optimization going on).  (Of course, that is an implementation detail that has no effect on the calling code, but it's an example of where you wouldn't have a backing ivar.)

Comment: @LuisOscar Conceptually, imagine a `rectangle` class. Two properties presumably backed by ivars would be `-length` and `-width`.  Another property might be `-area` - but it *wouldn't* be backed by an ivar.  It would calculate, at run-time, the area from the length and width.